# How to write a sql to select records with specific conditions

Tags: sql, oracle

Need to select from a same column based on specific conditions from a same table

I tried using max case when `status =‘OP’` then `tot_amount`else 0
Max case when `status =‘PR’` and `curr_flag =‘Y’` then`tot_amount` else 0

Below is the table

```
ID Type Status tot_Amount  curr_flag
1   Null OP      100           N
1.  F.   PR     60             N
1.  H.   PR.     0.            Y
```

Expected output

```
ID Type.  TotalAmt Bal-Amt 
1.  H.    100.     0
```

Comment: Please show the actual SQL you tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want conditional aggregation :

```
select id, 
       max(case when curr_falg = 'Y' then Type end) as Type,
       sum(case when Status = 'OP' then tot_Amount else 0 end) as TotalAmt,
       sum(case when Status = 'PR' and curr_falg = 'Y' then tot_Amount else 0 end) as Bal_Amt 
from table t
group by id;
```